# Enumerator for an alphabet in python

Tags: python, list, enumeration

Given:
`alphabet = ['a','b','c',...,'z']` 
i want python to enumerate every combination (starting from 1 lettered words to for example 1000 lettered words) of a word. For example (if i want every combination of a word of length 10) it should start like this:

```
[a,b,c,d...,z,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,...,aaa,aba,aca,ada,...,aab,aac,aad,....,zzzzzzzzzz]
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: why do you need the list? you can with a bit o math-magic generate an item in the list with the correspondent index...

Comment: Keep in mind there are 146,813,779,479,510 possible words just up to length 10. You could NEVER (and I mean literally never) generate all combinations up to length 1,000.

Comment: Adding this here because there are so many wrong answers I'm going to stop trying to comment on all of them -- `combinations` and `combinations_with_replacement` don't give the right answer. Neither will give both `aba` and `aab`, for example. Only `product` will generate both.

Comment: i think if you transform the index of the desired list into the string representation base 26 you get the correspondent word. Ex. index 27 -> 11 or aa. to list all possible word to 1000 is madness.

Comment: Yes i know that the numbers become mind-boggling, but i need this enumerator to create some set of words, that make this whole "recursively enumerable" thing with Turing-Machines concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you're looking for:

```
import itertools

max_length = 10
result = (''.join(word) for word in 
             itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                 itertools.product(alphabet, repeat = i)
                     for i in range(1, max_length + 1)))
```

You need to use a generator for this because there are simply too many possible words (even at length 10) for it to be possible to store them all in memory on a desktop computer.

Comment: this only prints: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x02AADC38>

Comment: @kiltek You have to iterate over in in a `for` loop -- `for word in result: do_something`. Go ahead and try the code in the answer you selected -- it doesn't work for words longer than six letters. Neither does the code in Ric's answer.

Comment: This is even better, i can set maxlength higher than the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `product` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product

result = []
for i in range(1, 5):
  alphabets = [alphabet] * i
  for x in product(*alphabets):
    result.append(''.join(x))
```

Yes, this works on my machine. But don't run it with 1000.

Comment: what is do_something ? what is alphabets?

Comment: Actually, there are more strings at length 7 than there are bytes of memory in most desktop computers. So there is no way you can run this code for strings of length 9.

Answer (score 1):

**Updating after noticing that you care about order**

You have to use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and iterate over it:

```
result = []
for r in range(1, 4):
    result.extend(''.join(i) for i in product(alphabet, repeat=r))
```

Simple check:

```
>>> 'dog' in result
True
>>> 'god' in result
True
```

Or without the generator expression:

```
for r in range(1, 4):
    for i in product(alphabet, repeat=r):
        result.append(''.join(i))
```

---

### Let's talk about madness

Every solution here can't handle long words, that's beacuse there are way too many possible combinations (it's anybody's fault). I don't care if this implementation can handle only words shorter than "epicalyx", while agf answer can handle up to 10 letters.

This kind of approach should only be used for small words.

> *"i want python to enumerate every combination (starting from 1 lettered words to for example **1000** lettered words)"* - Is waht the OP said.

**Nobody in his sane mind should even try to enumerate all those possiblities this way, and everybody who thinks that or that is tryng to push that limit is just plain mad and should really take a look at [ChessMaster great comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892478/enumerator-for-an-alphabet-in-python/9892622#comment12618965_9892478).**

Comment: This doesn't produce all possible words up to the correct length. `dog` and `god` are two different words.

Comment: But now it will only work for, at absolute most, words with 7 letters. And there are already three other answers showing this method.

Comment: Running this for more than that is just madness. This solution works just fine for health minded people.

Comment: Hi, the second solution without the generator expression suited my needs best. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider here is

1. [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from range 1 upto n, where n is the max word size would give the desired result.
2. You should use generator or else you would exhaust all memory soon

Here is one such implementation

```
>>> def foo(somelist,n):
    return (''.join(x) for i in xrange(1,n+1) for x in itertools.product(somelist, repeat=i))
```

You can call the generator foo in the following manner

```
>>> for i in foo(string.ascii_lowercase,10):
    print i,
```